# Laravel Dompdf - Error al exportar resultados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, blade

tengo este código en mi controlador de laravel para generar un archivo pdf

```
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('users.exportPdf', compact('preguntas'));
        return $pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');
```

Le paso una vista que esta en blade y un array con las opciones a printar.

Al intentar ejecutar la ruta me devuelve el resultado por pantalla de esta forma tanto si hago ->stream o ->download()

[image: hp]

El código **html** de la plantilla en blade es este

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Exportación de resultados</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        .contenido{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #primero{
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Titulo de prueba</h1>
<hr>



<div class="contenido">
    <p id="primero">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore nihil illo odit aperiam alias rem voluptatem odio maiores doloribus facere recusandae suscipit animi quod voluptatibus, laudantium obcaecati quisquam minus modi.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que retorna es un PDF, pero no está renderizando bien, estás seguro de que le agregaste UTF-8 en el header con `<meta>`?

Comment: Adjunto el código html en el post principal. Gracias @L.Flor

Comment: @ilernet lo pudistes solucionar?